# Is there a floating joint in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

URDF description of the robot allows to specify a 'floating' joint -- a joint with 6 degrees of freedom. But when the robot description gets translated into SDF, the floating joint is converted into fixed joint. Is there a way how to achieve a floating joint in Gazebo? I want to completely control the child link's movement with my plugin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24001/is-there-a-floating-joint-in-gazebo?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [awck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/37298/awck/) on 2020-12-04**:
Hi, did you figure out a way to do 6DOF pose control of a robot model in Gazebo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A floating joint in Gazebo (SDF) is just no joint

Unlike URDF, links in SDF can just exist as children of the robot model without being connected to each other in a tree structure.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0